# Problems with array error

Tags: php

Hello stackoverflow people, can you help me with this error,

> Warning: array_combine() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given
>   in

```
$check = mysql_query("SELECT user_task_types, user_task_types_id FROM dotp_user_task_type WHERE user_id = '$user_id'");
$row[] = mysql_fetch_array($check);
$check = array_combine($row[0], $row[1]);
```

Cant understand what is wrong with it. Ive tried doing [] this so it would be array but still nothng. My array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => TVS darbai
    [user_task_types] => TVS darbai
    [1] => 14
    [user_task_types_id] => 14
)
```

I want to connect user task type id with user task types it would look like [14] => TVS darbai

Comment: How many rows do you have in your table?Why do you use the same variable for query and for storing data?

Comment: Change `$row[] = mysql_fetch_array($check);` to `$row = mysql_fetch_array($check);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$row[] =` **appends** to an array. Your array now looks like:

```
array(
    0 => array(...)
)
```

As you see, there's no `[1]`. You probably just want `$row = mysql_fetch_array(..)`, then `$row[0]` corresponds to the first column and `row[1]` to the second. It would still not make sense to `array_combine` those two columns though.

You probably want this:

```
$result = mysql_query(...);
$check  = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $check[$row[0]] = $row[1];
}
```

Comment: But it prints now only last database row. for example if there are two rows:
TVS 15 and KMS 6 ir writes only KMS 6. Should i create loop?

Comment: Of course. `mysql_fetch_array` fetches a single row! If you want to fetch all, you need to loop.

Comment: What should i use then? Because this doesnt work: `while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 $check  = array($row[1] => $row[0]);
}`

Answer (score 0):

You no need to combine. `$row` gives your output

```
$check = mysql_query("SELECT user_task_types, user_task_types_id FROM dotp_user_task_type WHERE user_id = '$user_id'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($check) )
{
    echo $row;
}
```